# Expo v31 Android release build would not load JS bundle ( iOS build works on both debug and release configs)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

[image]

Environment
Expo CLI 2.6.14 environment info:
System:
OS: macOS 10.14.2
Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:

```
Node: 8.11.4 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.9.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 5.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
@storybook/react-native: ^3.2.5 => 3.4.11
expo: ^31.0.4 => 31.0.6
react: 16.5.0 => 16.5.0
react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.1.tar.gz => 0.57.1
react-navigation: v1.0.0-beta.26 => 1.0.0-beta.26
npmGlobalPackages:
expo-cli: 2.6.14
```

**Steps to Reproduce**

We have detached version of app that uses Expo v31.0.0. In iOS App works fine. (Both debug and release versions). But in Android, only debug version works. When we try to run a release build, App woudln't load. Apparently the JS bundle is not loading. We have correctly set up release-config.

Published JS bundle usingexp publishcommand (we tried expo publish too)
Created an APK and launched on an Android device.
Expected Behavior
App should load.

**Actual Behavior**

Only splash screen loads, then this error pops up.

Only Android release build has this issue. What could be the reason ?

Comment: What is shown when you click `View error log`?